# AutoInstrumentation of Quarkus Application(java)

Tags: java, quarkus, trace, instrumentation, open-telemetry

I traversed too many articles but didn't find anything about auto-instrumentation of Quarkus application,

Manual Instrumentation for Quarkus application is given below.

adding this implementetion will automatically add all the required dependency for tracing to app.

```
implementation 'io.quarkus:quarkus-opentelemetry-exporter-otlp'
```

In application.properties after mentioning required configurations , we will be able to send traces to collector.

```
quarkus.application.name=manualInstrumentationForQuarkus
quarkus.opentelemetry.enabled=true
quarkus.opentelemetry.tracer.exporter.otlp.endpoint=http://localhost:4317
quarkus.opentelemetry.tracer.exporter.otlp.headers=Authorization=Bearer my_secret
```

Please answer me with any autoinstrumentation method where we can use agent to get traces from application without adding any dependency.

Comment: https://opentelemetry.io/docs/instrumentation/java/automatic/ looks like agent configuration, it is not related to quarkus itself is it ?

Answer (score 1):

The recommended way to use OpenTelemetry on Quarkus is using the extension dependency you mention.
The [OpenTelemetry Java Agent](https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-java-instrumentation#getting-started) would provide some output but there are many context switching situations that will fail with the agent, leading to missing spans.